# Rust + WebGL is slow when the gl context is from outside of Rust

Tags: javascript, rust, webgl

I am doing some experiment with Rust and webgl. I have an interesting problem.

I have used the rust lib to create the webgl context like:

```rust
pub fn new(canvas: HtmlCanvasElement, ctx_info: ContextInfo) -> Self {
    let gl = canvas
        .get_context_with_context_options("webgl2", &ctx_info.create_js())
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap()
        .dyn_into::<WebGl2RenderingContext>()
        .unwrap();
}
```

Then I have configured it to pass the gl(from js) to Rust like :

```js
const canvas = parameters.canvas;
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', {
    premultipliedAlpha: parameters.premultipliedAlpha,
    alpha: parameters.alpha,
    antialias: parameters.antialias,
    depth: true,
    stencil: true,
});

WebGL2RenderingContext);
this.renderer = RendererHandleWASM.new(parameters.canvas, ctx, gl);
```

All the rest rendering logic inside the Rust is same.

I found that there is no FPS difference on my desktop with the Integrated graphics cards.

but when I test running it on my Macbook pro, which has a AMD Radeon Pro 5500M card, the FPS drops down to like half.

Any ide what causes this?

Comment: Please fix your javascript code and state the crate that you have used for Rust

Comment: thanks for correcting my spelling and grammar.
for the rust crate, i just used the web-sys lib, which is a very common one.

Comment: Are you testing in the same browsers and operating systems? Sounds like maybe you're software-rendering on the Macbook or just power-saving on the iGPU.

Comment: nah, i just switch the context from rust inside to a parameter outside from js, running on a same browser with same test environment, not sure why this happens